# SonarQube Generic Execution Report is ignored

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, e2e-testing

The whole morning I have been trying to setup e2e tests reporting via SonarQube's Generic Execution, by using the Generic Test Data -> Generic Execution feature.

I created a custom xml report that gets added to the scan properties like this:

`sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=**/e2e-report.xml`

So far, SonarQube seems to completely ignore this property and I no attempt to parse the file in the logs. Has anyone made it work?

These are links by Sonar about the Generic Execution feature:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data
- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/genericcoverage/GenericTestExecutionSensor.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a SonarQube 6.2+ feature. Make sure to use an appropriate SonarQube version.

In addition `sonar.testExecutionReportPaths` does not allow matchers (like `*`).

Please provide relative or absolute paths, comma separated.

See also:

- [The official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data#GenericTestData-GenericCoverage) of the Generic Test Data feature
- [The source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/genericcoverage/GenericTestExecutionSensor.java#L78), that looks up the generic execution files

Comment: You answer is correct. However, the root cause for my issue is that I am using Sonar 6.1 and this feature is 6.2+.

Comment: @miguelr Thank you for pointing this out. You saved me hours of frustration!